# rails, when rendering a partial, each render outputs in the log. Is this a performance hit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example if looping over @feed, which renders a partial, you see the following in the log:

```
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (2.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.6ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (2.8ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (2.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.8ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.6ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered feeds/_feed_item.html.erb (1.6ms)
```

Is that a performance hit? Is there a better way to handle this so it doesn't output every time?

Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to say that rendering partials in general is slower than not having partials. They are great for code organization and modularity of course, but if you can avoid it that will also help performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a performance hit. Render a collection.

Comment: Thanks... how do you do that?

Comment: I render 10 items using collection and does not see noticeable performance gain.